# Unable to ssh into one EC2 instance from another in same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to ssh from one EC2 instance (in-ports:22,443) to another DB server (another EC2) in-port 3306 sg-group of first ec2 group.

**EC2 Instance 1:** Security group A- Inbound: Port 22 & 443, Source: '0.0.0.0/0'

**EC2 Instance 2 (DB Server):** Security group B- Inbound: Port 3306, Source: 'Security group A'

When I try to ping 2 from 1, the connection times out.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to actually `ssh` from server 1 to server 2, or are you trying to connect to the database on server 2 from server 1? Your question is very unclear, it says you want to ssh to port 3306, which makes no sense. SSH works over port 22 by default. Port 3306 is the default MySQL database port.

The way your security groups are currently configured, you can SSH into server 1, and you can use a MySQL client on server 1 to connect to the MySQL database on server 2.

If you want to also `ssh` from server 1 to server 2, then you need top add a rule to Security group B: Inbound: Port 22, Source 'Security group A'.

You shouldn't worry about ping. The protocol for `ping` (ICMP) is currently blocked by your security groups, so `ping` isn't going be a useful test.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation. I'm trying to connect to mysql db residing on server 2(db server) by SSH into server1(webserver).

Comment: Well that's confusing because you didn't show anything in your question where you are trying to create a MySQL connection. Are you trying to setup SSH port forwarding or something? Or are you just trying to connect to MySQL from on server 2 using a MySQL client on server 1 (which has nothing to do with SSH).